# set java security policy via parameter instead of file

Tags: java, rmi, java-security

i don't want to use a security.policy file for just setting one line.
I thought about something like this:

`-Djava.security.policy="permission java.security.AllPermission"`

as parameter for the JVM. Is this possible? Is it possible to set a java security policy without specifying a file?

I also don't want to set the property in the code directly..

Comment: Is [this webpage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1274/configuring-the-default-jvm-and-java-arguments.html) be of any use for you?

Comment: If you want to grant `AllPermission` why are you using a security manager at all?

Comment: @ZeldaZach How is this useful? I can't see any argument about overwriting security policies via arguments instead of linking to a policy file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, you can only specify URL to another security policy file.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve a security poilicy without a file.

Comment: Could you please list them?

Comment: See [java.security.Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html). The standard implementation uses a file, but you can provide any implementation you like.

Comment: You can provide only different file, but you can't just supply parameter without file.

Comment: No. See the link I gave you. You can provide any `Policy` class that implements policies any way it likes. Not just 'different files'. You could trivially write a class that interpreted `java.security.policy` directly as `Permission` specifications.

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: Read it again why? What part of 'you could trivially write a [`Policy`] class that interpreted java.security.policy directly as Permission specifications' didn't you understand?

Comment: The question was: is it possible to supply command line arguments (without specifying a file)

Comment: And the claim in your answer that `there is no way to do that` is definitely false, because 'you could trivially write a [`Policy`] class that interpreted `java.security.policy` directly as `Permission` specifications', which is exactly what the OP asked for. If you don't understand that, please say so.

Comment: OP asked how to set security.policy via command line arguments without specifying a file and without any other programatic means (read : I also don't want to set the property in the code directly).

Comment: I didn't say anything about set[ting] the property in the code directly'. Do read what I actually wrote. If you don't understand it, say so. The class I mentioned would read the content of `java,security.policy` as a `Permission` *however it was set*, whether by the code or `-Djava,security.policy`. I cannot understand what made you think otherwise.

Comment: You can also create a whole framework just to acquire command line arguments. The point was to achieve without any additional efforts, with out of box functionality.

Comment: Glad to see you have finally understood, but there is nothing in the question about 'out of the box', and this is a programming site. The real question is why use a security manager at all, just to grant `AllPermission`? Your answer remains incorrect as stated.

Comment: My interpretation of the question is 'out of the box functionality', your interpretation could be different.

Comment: @Geek If he doesn't want to write a class he should say so. I'm not interested in guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

See [`java.security.Policy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html). The standard implementation uses a file, and assumes that `java.security.policy` points to a file, but you can provide any implementation you like, including one that behaves exactly as you have described.

But if you're only going to use this to grant yourself `AllPermission` it is hard to see why you're using a security manager at all.

Comment: because I use Java RMI and therefore I am forced to use a Security Manager.

Comment: @shibumi No you're not. The security manager is only required if you use the codebase feature.

Comment: Can a self-written `SecurityManager` or `Policy` be used in a JVM launched via command line? If yes, how would that command line look like? `java -Djava.security.manager=??? -Djava.security.policy="permission java.security.AllPermission"`?